# How do I dynamically set object attributes from a YAML file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML file which maps a bunch of properties to a class. I'd like to be able to loop through all of the properties from my YAML file and set them on an object dynamically.

How can I do this?

Here's the gist of what I have so far:

YAML contents:

```
my_obj:
    :username: 'myuser'
    :password: 'mypass'
    ...
```

Ruby:

```
settings = YAML::load_file SETTINGS_FILE
settings = settings['my_obj']

settings.each do |s|
  #psuedo-code
  #example: my_obj.username = settings[:username] if my_obj.has_property?(:username)
  #my_obj.[s] = settings[:s] if my_obj.has_property?(:s)
end
```

I'm not sure if doing this is necessarily a best practice, but there are a lot of properties and I thought this would be a cleaner way than manually setting each property directly.

Comment: give the content of `yaml` file..then it would be easy to answer your questions..

Comment: you want to have all properties in YAML mapped to object, consider using method_missing in that case.. :)

Comment: this is not valid `yaml`..give me the exact one..

Comment: @Priti, yes it is. The '...' is just to tell you there are a lot more properties that I'm not going to list out.

Comment: see my answer and tell me what next you want?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you actually need, you may be able to use Ruby’s default YAML dump and load behaviour. When dumping an arbitrary object to YAML, Psych (the Yaml parser/emitter in Ruby) will look at all the instance variables of the object and write out a Yaml mapping with them. For example:

```
class MyObj
  def initialize(name, password)
    @name = name
    @password = password
  end
end

my_obj = MyObj.new('myuser', 'mypass')

puts YAML.dump my_obj
```

will print out:

```yaml
--- !ruby/object:MyObj
name: myuser
password: mypass
```

You can then load this back with `YAML.load` and you will get an instance of `MyObj` with the same instance variables as your original.

You can override or customise this behaviour by implementing `encode_with` or `init_with` methods on your class.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample *yaml* file content,you would get the below `Hash`.

```
require 'yaml'
str = <<-end
my_obj:
  :username: 'myuser'
  :password: 'mypass'
end
settings = YAML.load(str)  
# => {"my_obj"=>{:username=>"myuser", :password=>"mypass"}}
settings['my_obj'][:username] # => "myuser"
settings['my_obj'][:password] # => "mypass"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to set my_obj properties from the settings hash.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I am not ordering you to do anything, just adding clarification so that your efforts are not in vain.

Comment: @doremi As per your yaml content you would get this Hash.. Now tell me what next you want?

Comment: I have a solution (see my answer). Perhaps you can offer a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll see this used a lot in Ruby gems and Rails. Here's a dummy class:

```
require 'yaml'

class MyClass
  attr_accessor :username, :password
  def initialize(params)
    @username, @password = params.values_at(*[:username, :password])
  end
end
```

We can load the data in using YAML's `load_file`:

```
data = YAML.load_file('test.yaml') # => {"my_obj"=>{:username=>"myuser", :password=>"mypass"}}
```

Passing the structure just read, which in this case is a hash, and which, oddly enough, or maybe even magically, is what the class initializer takes, creates an instance of the class:

```
my_class = MyClass.new(data['my_obj'])
```

We can see the instance variables are initialized correctly from the contents of the YAML file:

```
my_class.username # => "myuser"
my_class.password # => "mypass"
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working. It allows me to set attributes on `my_obj` dynamically from the YAML settings hash.

```
settings.each do |key, value|
  my_obj.instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) if my_obj.method_defined?("#{key}")
end
```

`my_obj` has `attr_accessor :username, :password`, etc.

The snippet above appears to let me set these attributes dynamically using [`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set), while also ensuring that `my_obj` has the attribute I'm trying to assign with [`method_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F).

Comment: This is similar to the default behaviour, see: https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb#L355

Comment: Default behavior of what?

Comment: Sorry, I commented after writing my answer – I guess I carried the context over from there. It’s the default behaviour of the Ruby Yaml parser when deserializing arbitrary objects.

Comment: What happens when yaml tries to dump an attr to the obj that doesn't exist?

Comment: You mean it isn’t defined / referred to in the source? Nothing really, the object just has an extra instance variable attached to it. In Ruby you can pretty much add any instance variables to any object: `Object.new.instance_variable_set('@foo', 'bar')`.